# How many schedule K-1 's would I receive If i trade the ETF on 2 different brokers?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf

This year, I have traded several Commodity ETFs, such as USO, BNO, OILK ( crude oil funds), UGL (Proshares Gold Fund). These ETFs are structured as Limited Partnership. I know that around mid-March next year(2021), I will receive K-1 forms(that lists the shared income, deductions, credits...) for those ETFs.

I put my money in 2 different brokerage accounts (TD Ameritrade and Fidelity). I have used the funds in those 2 accounts to buy the same ETFs, like BNO. I'm wondering , next year, for an ETF(like BNO), I would receive only 1 schedule K-1 from the fund, or 2 different K-1's (for 2 brokers)?